# Hacer consultas a mysql desde php usando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

que tal mi problema es que necesito traer datos de una consulta pero al parecer me trae datos vacios y creo que mi problema puede estar en el modo que hago la consulta.
Tengo el siguiente codigo en un php para conexion a la base de datos (resumido  ya que elimine lo que considere innecesario puesto que la conexion si se realiza correctamente)

```
   return $this->conexion= new PDO($url,$usuario,$password);
```

en otro php tengo un constructor al que le mando el nombre de la tabla sobre el cual se va a trabajar y al mismo tiempo hago la conexion

```
public function __construct($tabla = null){
    $this->conexion = (new Conexion())->conectar();
    $this->tabla= $tabla;
}
```

en ese mismo PHP tengo un metodo get el cual hace el select

```
public function get(){
    try{
        $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->tabla} {$this->where}";
        $sth=$this->conexion->prepare($this->sql);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

en el index tengo lo siguiente

```
$crud = new Crud ("personas");
$lista=$crud->get();

var_dump($lista);
```

Pero al momento de mostrar el var_dump no obtengo resultados cabe mencionar que la tabla si tiene registros

Comment: ¿Cómo manejas el asunto del `WHERE` en tu clase? Tienes que hacer una verificación de si hay o no criterio `WHERE`, porque de lo contrario se podría estar creando una consulta SQL así: `SELECT * FROM personas NULL` lo cual es inválido. Para que el `var_dump` te informe del posible error, pon un `return` en el  `catch`, de este modo: `return $e->getTraceAsString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta sustituir `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` por `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` en `fetchAll`

Ejemplo:

```
public function get(){
    try{
        $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->tabla} {$this->where}";
        $sth=$this->conexion->prepare($this->sql);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```